# calculating time complexity of merging presorted lists without using extra memory

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, mergesort

Given a list of presorted arrays, i.e. `List<List<Integer>>`, I am using the following technique to sort them. Will someone please explain to me the time complexity? Here is the algorithm

```
List<Integer> merge(List<List<Integer>> lists){
    Queue<MyPriorityQueue> pqs = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int i=1; i<lists.size();i+=2){
        pqs.add(merge(lists.get(i-1),lists.get(i)));
    }
    if(lists.size()%2==1)pqs.add(merge(lists.get(lists.size()-1),null));

    while(pqs.size()>1) pqs.add( merge(pqs.poll(),pqs.poll()));

    MyPriorityQueue myPq = pqs.poll();
    List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();

    while(!myPq.isEmpty()){
        result.add(myPq.poll());
    }
    return result;
}
```

There are two `merge` methods.

```
MyPriorityQueue merge(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b){ return new MyPriorityQueue(a,b);}

MyPriorityQueue merge(MyPriorityQueue a, MyPriorityQueue  b){ return new MyPriorityQueue(a,b);}
```

Notice that the `merge` function essentially passes two iterators to the MyPriorityQueue constructor. So that when a call is made to `MyPriorityQueue#poll()`, the two iterators are compared and the greater value is returned. Hence, we are not using extra memory.

Now let’s compare to normal mergeSort. Normally mergeSort uses extra memory: each call to merge(x, y) would simply create a third list z and put all the elements in x and y into z. That approach would result in time O(n lg n). But in my present approach, we are not using the extra memory. So that each time I call #poll(), I have to walk the tree to find the smallest element. This to me means O(n^2) for the line  `while(!myPq.isEmpty()){result.add(myPq.poll());}`. But someone had told me that the time complexity is actually still O(n lg n). I can’t see how. Will someone please explain the time complexity to me?

We are not doing log n comparisons a number of n times, are we? Per my visualization, if there are n lists on the tree and I call `myPq.poll())`, then we are doing n comparisons.

So basically let's say there are n lists and each list has an average of k elements in them. The time complexity of the algorithm seems to me

`log n + (n+k)*n`. It takes log n to create the pqs tree and get the root; then it takes (n+k)*n to add all the elements to result as `while(!myPq.isEmpty()){result.add(myPq.poll());}`

**UPDATE: Here is an actual implementation in Java**

```
import java.util.*;


public class MergePresortedLists {


    List<Integer> merge(List<List<Integer>> lists) {

        Queue<PQ> pqs = new LinkedList<>();

        for (int i = 1; i < lists.size(); i += 2) {

            pqs.add(merge(lists.get(i - 1), lists.get(i)));

        }

        if (lists.size() % 2 != 0)

            pqs.add(merge(lists.get(lists.size() - 1), null));

        while (pqs.size() > 1) {

            pqs.add(merge(pqs.poll(), pqs.poll()));

        }

        PQ pq = pqs.poll();


        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

        while (!pq.isEmpty()) {

            result.add(pq.poll());

        }

        return result;

    }


    private PQ merge(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {

        return new PQ(a, b);

    }


    private PQ merge(PQ a, PQ b) {

        return new PQ(a, b);

    }


    class PQ {


        List<Integer> a, b;

        int sizeA = -1, sizeB = -1;


        PQ x, y;


        public PQ(List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2) {

            a = l1;

            b = l2;

            if (null != a)

                sizeA = a.size() - 1;

            if (null != b)

                sizeB = b.size() - 1;

        }


        public PQ(PQ q1, PQ q2) {

            x = q1;

            y = q2;

        }


        public int size() {

            int listsSize = sizeA + sizeB + 2;

            int qSize = null == x ? 0 : y.size();

            qSize += null == y ? 0 : x.size();

            return listsSize > qSize ? listsSize : qSize;

        }


        public boolean isEmpty() {

            return size() == 0;

        }


        public Integer poll() {

            if (sizeA > -1 || sizeB > -1) {

                return listPoll();

            }


            Integer xPeek = (x != null && !x.isEmpty()) ? x.peek() : null;

            Integer yPeek = (y != null && !y.isEmpty()) ? y.peek() : null;

            if (null != xPeek || null != yPeek) {

                return qPoll(xPeek, yPeek);

            }

            return null;

        }


        private Integer listPoll() {

            if (sizeA > -1 && sizeB > -1) {

                return a.get(sizeA) > b.get(sizeB) ? a.get(sizeA--) : b.get(sizeB--);

            } else if (sizeA > -1)

                return a.get(sizeA--);

            else

                return b.get(sizeB--);

        }


        private Integer qPoll(Integer xPeek, Integer yPeek) {

            if (null != xPeek && null != yPeek) {

                return xPeek > yPeek ? x.poll() : y.poll();

            } else if (null != xPeek)

                return x.poll();

            else

                return y.poll();

        }


        public Integer peek() {

            if (sizeA > -1 || sizeB > -1) {

                return listPeek();

            }


            Integer xPeek = null != x ? x.peek() : null;

            Integer yPeek = null != y ? y.peek() : null;

            if (null != xPeek || null != yPeek) {

                return qPeek(xPeek, yPeek);

            }

            return null;

        }


        private Integer listPeek() {

            if (sizeA > -1 && sizeB > -1) {

                return a.get(sizeA) > b.get(sizeB) ? a.get(sizeA) : b.get(sizeB);

            } else if (sizeA > -1)

                return a.get(sizeA);

            else

                return b.get(sizeB);

        }

        private Integer qPeek(Integer xPeek, Integer yPeek) {

            if (null != xPeek && null != yPeek) {

                return xPeek > yPeek ? xPeek : yPeek;

            } else if (null != xPeek) return xPeek;

            else return yPeek;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: A tiny nit: the complexity of merging two presorted lists _A_ and _B_ into a third list is _O(length(A) + length(B))_, and all you have to do is to scan both lists in parallel once, picking elements into a third list. You seem to count it as logarithmic.

Comment: You are just describing the merging part of merge sort. But this is not just two lists. It's n lists. You are missing that part.

Comment: You seem to use extra memory, despite your stated goal: you allocate `result` which has to contain the merged list. A proper implementation would have to mutate one of the input lists, while deallocating the rest of the input lists. The cost of merging in-place seems to greatly depend on the cost of removing items form a particular list or adding them in the middle of the list. It differs dramatically between e.g. `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`. It seems that merging two pre-sorted _linked_ lists can be done in linear time, much like merging two lists into a third one.

Comment: Not using extra memory, with all those `new MyPriorityQueue(...)` calls?

Comment: @RealSkeptic: The priority queue seems to have the size of the _number_ of input lists, not their sizes; for 2 lists it would be of size 2 — at least, initially. This happens every recursive invocation, though, so the size _does_ grow with the size of input.

Comment: these are basic overheads. They are pointers to nodes on the tree. I describe precisely what is meant by extra memory: using an extra list z of size |z| = |x|+|y| at every merge sort to merge x and y into z.

Comment: @9000 The fact that there is a flexible size to the list means that there is an input size to reckon with. There is going to be a different memory footprint if you have 10 lists of 2 items or 2 lists of 10 items. Memory complexity needs to take all input sizes into account. This is *not* a constant!

Comment: Hint: You _cannot_ merge two `ArrayList`s without allocating some extra memory, because `ArrayLists` grow and shrink their actual memory buffers in large extents, and you cannot snatch an element from one `ArrayList` and insert it into another, keeping the memory constant. I suggest that you limit yourself to a linked list (or a tree), and write an implementation that merges two pre-sorted lists in linear time and constant space, _moving_ nodes from one list to another (a `TreeList` will just do it for you automatically!). After that, you'll see how to extend this to more than 2 lists.

Comment: @9000 yes you can. I just show you how. Treat each presorted ArrayList as an iterator and pass both to a priority list that you yourself define. When some calls `poll()` you simple return the greater of the two elements. You never have to remove anything from the ArrayLists; just use an index for each and decrement the index as you go. Can't you see it? I will add a Java implementation, then.

Comment: Dude, based on the answers you have been getting so far, I would say this is not the best place to ask this question as most people seems to not even know that it can be implemented. Maybe there is a computer science forum on StackExchance, I don't know. I personally understand the implementation that you have --without using extra ArrayLists at each merge call. But I don't know how to compute the time complexity of the loop that adds elements to `result`.

Comment: @NouvelTravay: You can absolutely fetch items in sorted order from a few lists in sorted order. It's trivial. But where do you _put_ these items? Your solution puts it into a `result` list, **in direct contradiction** to the stated goal of _«without using extra memory»_.

Comment: @9000 now that the problem statement is clear, there is no need that you should keep missing the point. The question is about not using an extra ArrayList inside each merge call. Assembling the final answer inside an ArrayList as `result` is to emphasize the behavior of `PQ#poll`. The question still remains: what is the time complexity of `while(!myPq.isEmpty()){result.add(myPq.poll());}`. Clearly the question is above your head, and that's ok. I don't know the answer either. But I have no problem admitting it and hope someone else knows the answer and shares.

Comment: @KatedralPillon: I'd appreciate if you offer a better formulation of the question title then. It seems to have more to do with the time complexity of `.poll` of this particular queue implementation, and has nothing to do with that memory allocation thing.

Comment: @NouvelTravay: Would "calculating time complexity of merging presorted lists using priority queues" be an adequate title for your question?

Comment: @9000 The problem is: **Can I merge n presorted lists without using extra memory inside each merge subroutine? What is the time complexity?** The reason we cannot say LinkedList is because each of pre-sorted list may be an input stream as opposed to a "physical" list on the local machine.

Comment: @NouvelTravay: OK, we have streams, so we cannot mutate anything in place. I understand the "no extra memory" requirement as "we stream out the results and do not count this as allocation"; otherwise you'd need the memory of the size of sum of all input streams. To me, this looks linear still. Keep _n_ values, each for the current "top" of each stream. On each step, pick the smallest of them, and send to the output stream; replenish a value from that stream. To handle the EOF situations, keep _n_ booleans; only consider streams that  haven't ended yet. Finish when all streams are over.

Comment: I frankly don't see where a priority queue may belong here. The output "stream" can be an `ArrayList` with a "current position" counter attached, or a linked list, or anything that has a kind of "append to the end" operation.

Comment: Also we cannot specify PriorityQueue in the title because that's an implementation choice. Whatever auxiliary data-structure gets the job done is fine by me as well as the supervisor, etc. I choose priority queue because it allows me to treat the input lists as iterators by simply pointing to them -- instead of keeping a "personal" copy. (sorry your two last comments just loaded. I didn't see them)